# Modify current view when at background state on iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

iOS7 comes with new feature to see, switch and close running apps.

[image]

But that may be a problem to some of the apps. I'm developing for a client that inside have sensitive data, and after user leaving / closing the app, it can still be seen in the running app, somehow the iOS7 cache the last image.

So I was wondering how to somehow cater this, and I stumbled across PayPal app. he did great job, by blurring the image. I try to do exactly that.

[image]

My progress so far has no luck. this is what I did so far.
I use `applicationDidEnterBackground` & `applicationWillEnterForeground` to add/remove subview of an image (blurry image/transparent) on top of current view. But it didn't work.

Any helps would appreciated.

Comment: Ops. silly mistake. forgot to add the image. apparently I was blurring empty image all the time.

Comment: Please consider posting an answer to your own question with thed etails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>App screenshot is taken before `applicationDidEnterBackground` - *DidEnter* let you know it's already done.</s> Checked - I was wrong.

I suggest using `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` pair. It worked for me.

Comment: Good point. but the main problem isn't that. my code is correct since beginning :). thanks.